# Do C# Timers elapse on a separate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Does a System.Timers.Timer elapse on a separate thread than the thread that created it?

Lets say I have a class with a timer that fires every 5 seconds. When the timer fires, in the elapsed method, some object is modified. Lets say it takes a long time to modify this object, like 10 seconds. Is it possible that I will run into thread collisions in this scenario?

Comment: This could lead to problems.  Note that, in general, threadpool threads are not designed for long-running processes.

Comment: I was running into this, testing with a  windows service.  What worked for me was disabling the timer as the first instruction in the OnTimer event, performing my tasks, then enabling the timer at the end.   This has worked reliably in a production environment for some time.

Comment: I am surprised Monitor.TryEnter isn't mentioned as an approach here. Seems neater to me than most other approaches, such as stopping the timer. if (Monitor.TryEnter(someObkect) { ..do timer workload..} finally {monitor.exit()} You can also use the else clause to log that the timed event was skipped, maybe add logic to update the timer frequency too.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**For [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):**

See [Brian Gideon's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436331/314291)

**For [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):**

[MSDN Documentation on Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8.aspx) states:

> The System.Threading.Timer class **makes
>   callbacks on a ThreadPool thread** and
>   does not use the event model at all.

So indeed the timer elapses on a different thread.

Comment: True, but that is a completely different class.  The OP asked about the System.Timers.Timer class.

Comment: Oh, you're right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx says "The Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread." Same conclusion from there I suppose.

Comment: Well, yeah, but it is not quite that simple.  See my answer.

Answer (score 213):

It depends.  The `System.Timers.Timer` has two modes of operation.

If `SynchronizingObject` is set to an `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance then the `Elapsed` event will execute on the thread hosting the synchronizing object.  Usually these `ISynchronizeInvoke` instances are none other than plain old `Control` and `Form` instances that we are all familiar with.  So in that case the `Elapsed` event is invoked on the UI thread and it behaves similar to the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  Otherwise, it really depends on the specific `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance that was used.

If `SynchronizingObject` is null then the `Elapsed` event is invoked on a `ThreadPool` thread and it behaves similar to the `System.Threading.Timer`. In fact, it actually uses a `System.Threading.Timer` behind the scenes and does the marshaling operation *after* it receives the timer callback if needed.

Comment: If you wanted the timer callback to execute on a new thread, should you use a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: @cj7: Either one can do that.

Comment: and if I have a list of complex type (person) and want to have a time inside each person? I need this running on the same thread (all persons), because if it calls the first person method, the second person must wait until the first ends the elapsed event. Can I do that?

Comment: Everyone...`System.Timers.Timer` has two modes of operation. It can run on a randomly assigned thread pool thread OR it can run on whatever thread is hosting the `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance. I don't know how to make that any more clear. `System.Threading.Timer` has little (if anything) to do with the original question.

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes Can't you use `lock` for that?

Comment: Since the SynchronizingObject property's default value is null, your Elapsed event will happen on another thread unless you have set the SynchronizingObject property.

Comment: @BrianGideon Will a thread pool timer ALWAYS be a different thread than the one which is invoking the timer? WITHOUT an ISynchronizeInvoke object, is it somehow possible that the same thread will be used for the timer's callback?

Answer (score 25):

Each elapsed event will fire in the same thread unless a previous Elapsed is still running.

So it handles the collision for you

try putting this in a console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

you will get something like this

```
10
6
12
6
12
```

where 10 is the calling thread and 6 and 12 are firing from the bg elapsed event.
If you remove the Thread.Sleep(2000); you will get something like this

```
10
6
6
6
6
```

Since there are no collisions.

But this still leaves u with a problem. if u are firing the event every 5 seconds and it takes 10 seconds to edit u need some locking to skip some edits.

Comment: Adding a `timer.Stop()` at the beginning of the Elapsed event method and then a `timer.Start()` at the end of the Elapsed event method will keep the Elapsed event from colliding.

Comment: You don't need to put timer.Stop() you just need to define timer.AutoReset = false; then you make timer.Start() after you process the event. I think this is a better way you avoid collisions.

Comment: if Monitor.TryEnter

Answer (score 17):

For System.Timers.Timer, on separate thread, if SynchronizingObject is not set.

```
    static System.Timers.Timer DummyTimer = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Id: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            DummyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 5); // 5 sec interval
            DummyTimer.Enabled = true;
            DummyTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnDummyTimerFired);
            DummyTimer.AutoReset = true;

            DummyTimer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        }

        return;
    }

    static void OnDummyTimerFired(object Sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return;
    }
```

Output you'd see if DummyTimer fired on 5 seconds interval:

```
Main Thread Id: 9
   12
   12
   12
   12
   12
   ...
```

So, as seen, OnDummyTimerFired is executed on Workers thread.

No, further complication - If you reduce interval to say 10 ms,

```
Main Thread Id: 9
   11
   13
   12
   22
   17
   ...
```

This is because if prev execution of OnDummyTimerFired isn't done when next tick is fired, then .NET would create a new thread to do this job.

Complicating things further, *"The System.Timers.Timer class provides an easy way to deal with this dilemma—it exposes a public SynchronizingObject property. Setting this property to an instance of a Windows Form (or a control on a Windows Form) will ensure that the code in your Elapsed event handler runs on the same thread on which the SynchronizingObject was instantiated."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2

Comment: That's a good example. I didn't know until now and i need to set some locks here and there. Perfect.

Comment: And what if I want the timer fires the Elapsed event in the main thread of a console application?

Answer (score 15):

If the elapsed event takes longer then the interval, it will create another thread to raise the elapsed event. But there is a workaround for this

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)    
{     
   try
   {
      timer.Stop(); 
      Thread.Sleep(2000);        
      Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);    
   }
   finally
   {
     timer.Start();
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 Simple and clean answer, but this will not work always. Rather one should use lock or SynchronizingObject property of timer.

Comment: You have an at least theoretical race condition here, that happens when the timer elapses again before the `Stop`is hit. Unlikely for bigger time periods though, but still not clean. Use a timer with `Autoreset` set to `false` and then the timer is disabled automatically when the event hits. You don't need to call `Stop` then.