# Does CLR internally spawns a thread to respond to timer events?

Tags: .net, clr, sscli

Hans and I had small discussion recently about the subject and I'm curious how it is really implemented.

See initial talking in the comments here: [Are c# timers naturally multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339553/are-c-timers-naturally-multithreaded/6339682#6339682)

Comment: Downvote because looking at this question and answers alone doesn't offer any information at all.  I have to go look at the other thread to get any input from "Hans" who you reference in the accepted answer and I have to go to your blog to get any details about how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did some investigations... Details are in my [blog post](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/clr-internals-implementation-of-net-timers/)

To be short, just summary from there:

- As for SSCLI20 Hans was totally right. There’s really separate thread for handing APCs and queued timers. Thanks for your insistence, btw. I received a chance to dig something interesting :)
- On newer systems it still could be implemented without additional threads. I was just mistakenly assuming it was already there when CLR 2.0 was written. For details see CreateThreadpoolTimer, SetThreadpoolTimer and CloseThreadpoolTimer.

Answer (score 2):

Staring at the .Net 4.0 reference source, `System.Timers.Timer` seems to use a `System.Threading.Timer` to handle the actual implementation details.  The latter generates timers by calling `AddTimerNative`.  `AddTimerNative` is an internal call.

Googling `AddTimerNative` lead to a lot of interesting results, including [Willy Denoyette](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/253711-how-many-timers)'s comment, where he states that it calls [CreateTimerQueueTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485.aspx).

That page states that "Callback functions are queued to the thread pool. "