# How does a C# Timer Object decide when an elapsed amount of time has occurred?

Tags: c#, timer

How does a C# Timer Object decide when an elapsed amount of time has occurred?

I am wondering if it simply loops or is more intelligent than this.

Also, it would be good to know where to find the C# Source Code to have a look through.

Comment: I think it is using a system timer or something like that. It is definitely not looping endlessly

Comment: @pengibot, the .NET source can be found here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: Also, you can de-compile the .NET assemblies, through tools such as [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

Comment: Without looking at the code, I am going to guess you will not get much from it.  It probably makes a call to the Win32 SetTimer method.  I don't know if there is source for that available.

Comment: Indeed, decompiling or viewing the source often comes in handy.

Comment: @Arran Thanks, downloading it now. Will give me a better idea of what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Getting this too! Thanks.

Comment: Here is an interesting article on [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343733/does-clr-internally-spawns-a-thread-to-respond-to-timer-events/6363808#6363808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET BCL has at least two classes providing timers:

- [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
- [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

However, the second class is implemented using the first. The first class uses some kind of native Win32 timer and Hans Passant has provided more information about the mechanism used. In the BCL source code the timer is implemented using an internal class named `TimerQueue`. The implementation of the `TimerQueue` class has this comment:

> TimerQueue maintains a list of active timers in this AppDomain.  We use a single native timer, supplied by the VM, to schedule all managed timers in the AppDomain.

So basically the AppDomain has a single time source implemented using unmanaged code. See Hans Passant's answer for more information on that.

---

> Also, it would be good to know where to find the C# Source Code to have a look through.

I use [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It can be configured to retrieve source files from Microsoft if they exist. Simply load in the version of .NET you want to examine, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, type "Timer", select the specific class you want and it will download the source if it exists. Otherwise you will see a decompiled version (depending on your configuration).

Note that this tool will only allow you to decomple managed code and to fully understand the implementation of timers in .NET you need to be able to peek further into unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, That dotPeek seems a very handy tool

Comment: You haven't found it.  Note that TimerQueue is in the System.Net assembly.  The timer classes you quote are in mscorlib and System.

Comment: @HansPassant: The class is the internal `System.Threading.TimerQueue` in `mscorlib` in .NET 4.5. However, I have updated my answer to reflect the more correct information you have provided.

Answer (score 8):

The CLR creates a dedicated thread that handles all timer objects you create in your application and gets their Elapsed event and callback handler running.  You can see it being used with the debugger.  Start with a console mode app that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t = Timer();
        t.Elapsed += ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) => { });
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the "Enable native code debugging" (aka unmanaged code) option.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols and ensure that the Microsoft Symbol Server is enabled.  Start debugging by pressing F11.

Now use Debug + Windows + Threads.  You'll see 4 threads listed.  Your main thread, the finalizer thread, the debugging thread and an idle threadpool thread.  Keep stepping until you stepped past the t.Start() method call.  Note that there's now a *new* thread added.  The name is "ThreadPoolMgr::TimerThreadStart".  Double-click it and look at the Call Stack window.  You'll see:

```
ntdll.dll!_NtDelayExecution@8()  + 0x15 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_NtDelayExecution@8()  + 0x15 bytes   
KernelBase.dll!_SleepEx@8()  + 0x39 bytes   
clr.dll!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire()  + 0x3e bytes  
clr.dll!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart()  + 0x6a bytes 
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

The important bits here are the TimerThreadStart() function, that's the start point for the thread that the CLR started.  And the SleepEx() call, that's this thread sleeping until the next timer is due.  This stack trace was for .NET 4.5, it has been consistent like this all the way back since .NET 2.0.  For which source code is available, you can have a look see at the SSCLI20 source code that you can [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).  Searching that code takes you to the clr/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp source code file.  Have a look at it to see what is going on.

I'll just briefly describe it.  The timing source is the GetTickCount() api function, the same one used by Environment.TickCount.  The FireTimers() function sorts out which of the active timers is due first.  The SleepEx() function is the same one as Thread.Sleep(), except that it is *alertable*.  It can be interrupted before the sleep is complete by an APC (asynchronous procedure call).  Which you see being used in that same file, QueueUserAPC() function when the thread needs to terminate because the program is shutting down and when a timer is added or modified so that a new sleep needs to be calculated.