# What thread does Timer use wile waiting?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task

In MS book for certification I see this part:

```
public Task SleepAsyncA(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout));
}
public Task SleepAsyncB(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    var t = new Timer(delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, -1);
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(t);
    t.Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

*The SleepAsyncA method uses a thread from the thread pool while sleeping. The second
method, however, which has a completely different implementation, does not occupy a
thread while waiting for the timer to run. The second method gives you scalability.*

**But**, does not Timer uses dedicated thread while waiting particular amount of time?

Comment: What kind of timer is it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6339682/43846

Comment: Yes it does.  It is however a thread that handles all active timers.  So it is "scalable".  You can see it when you enable unmanaged debugging, shows up as "clr.dll!ThreadPoolMgr::TimerThreadStart".  Do favor Task.Delay() instead of hoofing it yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant, Ok, so, it's because one thread for managing all timers, thanks!

Comment: @stuartd, this is Threading Timer yes