# What is the best way to implement a "timer"?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What is the best way to implement a timer? A code sample would be great! For this question, "best" is defined as most reliable (least number of misfires) and precise. If I specify an interval of 15 seconds, I want the target method invoked every 15 seconds, not every 10 - 20 seconds. On the other hand, I don't need nanosecond accuracy. In this example, it would be acceptable for the method to fire every 14.51 - 15.49 seconds.

Comment: Another great question being marked as duplicate without any useful link pointing to the duplicate that explains this well

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Use the [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class.

```
public static void Main()
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 5000; // ~ 5 seconds
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
    while(Console.Read() != 'q');
}

 // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
 }
```

The `Elapsed` event will be raised every X amount of milliseconds, specified by the `Interval` property on the Timer object. It will call the `Event Handler` method you specify. In the example above, it is `OnTimedEvent`.

Comment: Does the timer execute on a separate thread?

Comment: @VaughanHilts, short answer, Yes. Long answer, review [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436331/1630665) which explains what thread the timer elapses on very well.

Comment: `OnTimedEvent` isn't being recognized on my machine. I'm using System.Timers.

Comment: @kuhaku `OnTimedEvent` is the method defined underneath `Main`. It's not a framework method.

Comment: Do you have to set Enabled? Isn't it enabled by default?

Comment: By default Enabled is `false`. Enabled "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Timer should raise the Elapsed event". What this means is setting it to true starts the timer, and `timer.Enabled = true;` is equivalent to calling `timer.Start()`;

Comment: I've used the same MSDN documentation and I can only get this to fire once.

Comment: Why do we need to wrap `OnTimedEvent ` in a `ElapsedEventHandler` class? I tried without the wrapper but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielJackson I have the same problem.

Comment: Caution: `System.Timers.Timer` can cause memory leaks if you don't dispose of them properly because a running timer can keep the host class "active" an prevent garbage collection on it. A good rule of thumb is if you have any class that uses one of these timers, it should implement `IDisposable` and in its `Dispose` method, you should explicitly dispose the timer(s). OR in the example above, you could add `aTimer.Dispose()` after the `Console.Read` (although admittedly, since we would be doing this at the end of `Main`, that would make no material difference in this specific example).

Comment: `aTimer.Interval = 5000;` does it means it will restart after `5` seconds?

Comment: @Moeez yes because the time is in milliseconds

Comment: Another important point to consider is that, If the SynchronizingObject property is null (i.e aTimer.SynchronizingObject is null), the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

Answer (score 51):

By using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class you can achieve what you need.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


t.Interval = 15000; // specify interval time as you want
t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
t.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Call method
}
```

By using stop() method you can stop timer.

```
t.Stop();
```

Comment: If you have one, you can just drag a timer control onto your form from the Toolbox and it does all the above for you.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Yes, I agree with you. we can add timer control via toolbox. But approach which i shared is via runtime add timer.

Answer (score 35):

It's not clear *what type of application you're going to develop* (desktop, web, console...)

The general answer, if you're developing `Windows.Forms` application, is use of

[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class. The benefit of this is that it runs on `UI` thread, so it's simple just define it, subscribe to its [Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event and run your code on every 15 second.

If you do something else then windows forms (it's not clear from the question), you can choose [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), but *this* one runs on **other** thread, so if you are going to act on some UI elements from the its [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event, you have to manage it with "invoking" access.

Comment: best answer in this topic I think.

Comment: @Tigran, I am new to C# and I ran into exactly the same situation which you mentioned. Can you explain how can we invoke access because I am getting error of different thread for Windows Form and Timer running on different threads. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Reference `ServiceBase` to your class and put the below code in the `OnStart`event:

`Constants.TimeIntervalValue = 1` (hour)..Ideally you should set this value in config file.

StartSendingMails = function name you want to run in the application.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // It tells in what interval the service will run each time.
            Int32 timeInterval = Int32.Parse(Constants.TimeIntervalValue) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            base.OnStart(args);
            TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(StartSendingMails);
            serviceTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 0, Convert.ToInt32(timeInterval));
        }
```

Comment: -1 OP mentions a console app - there's no reason to bring the Windows Service classes in to this. Especially when, to solve the problem, you're using the same Timer class as the accepted answer.

Comment: this is shown in a service but applicable to any code. NOt to mention @TarkaDaal. console is not mentioned in this post. only in the possible duplicate.

Comment: 6 years late, But I might as well mention this answer is using "System.Threading.Timer" meanwhile the accepted answer is using "System.Timers.Timer". so it's not the same Timer class.