# Windows Phone 8 Handle event when the map stops scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

I am working on an application using map on WP8 and I have to know when does the map stop scrolling so I can send my asynchronous requests to the webservice to get my data.

The only event handler I found which could correspond is **ViewChanged** but the problem is that it is called while the map is still moving, and I only want to send requests to my server when the user stops scrolling where he wants.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution to it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fired only when the map has stopped changing that's why you have two different events: `ViewChanging` and `ViewChanged`.

See Maps events on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map_events(v=vs.105).aspx

Additionnaly, you can also use `CenterChanged` and `ZoomLevelChanged` that should be fired when the view has been updated.

- CenterChanged:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.centerchanged(v=vs.105).aspx

- ViewChanged:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.zoomlevelchanged(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you but actually viewChanged is called many times when the map is scrolling, it just means that the view changed, not that the map stopped to scroll.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try with CenterChanged, it should be fired only when the map has stopped moving. Another way would be to throttle the event and manage the calls with ViewChanging (if Changing is on, then wait 300 ms before calling the method)

Comment: I used a timer combined to CenterChanged as you said thank you.

For help with timer, this question may help others who encounter the same problem than me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer