# How do I add time to send API push message (parse.com) using .Net(C#)

Tags: c#, parse-platform, push-notification

I am going to push the message at the time which is  exactly what I want,but I don't know how to do that.

Now,I can send the message to ios or Android.

There is my code.Please help me to add the time in that.

```
ParseClient.Initialize("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");               

            var push = new ParsePush();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id))
            {
                push.Query = from install in ParseInstallation.Query
                             where install.Get<string>("NO") == Id
                             select install;
            }                
            push.Data = new Dictionary<string, object> {
              {"title", TitleMeg},
              {"alert", AlertMeg}
            };
            await push.SendAsync();
```

Comment: you use timer or schduler class to do this

Comment: @Jamie.Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer

Comment: thanks for answer.But I creating an Api by using prase push.

Comment: so the time will different

Comment: Does Prase api have way to do that?

Comment: Jest like this viedo [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq_fSMNWVbE)
you can go to 20:45 to see that.
But not using web site.Have to using code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution in C#.

I use Rset Api to do what I want.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.parse.com/1/push");

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] ="";
request.Headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "";
string json = json格式參考-d中的欄位 https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-scheduling-pushes
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqstr.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```