# C# MultiThreading is causing unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory

(Background)
I am creating a stock market emulation program to further my C# knowledge.
I previously created this program in Java.

(Issue)
In Java, I was able to create a new thread in order to have it loop and update my GUI's labels every x amount of time. I researched methods to do this in C# and came across the timer, this didn't work for me and so I resorted to multi-threading.

Upon startup of the form I create a new thread

```
    /// <summary>
    /// stock emulation startup
    /// </summary>
    public stockEmu()
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; //if this is true, then cross-thread changes cannot be made (repeater cannot set labels if true)

        initializeValues(); //this will set the startup values e.g stock prices and user money

        ThreadStart loopThread = new ThreadStart( repeater );   //opens a new thread
        Thread openThread = new Thread( loopThread );       //opens a new thread
        openThread.Start();                             //opens a new thread

        InitializeComponent(); //initializes the form

        this.updateLabels(); //needs to be after initializecomponent or null exception is thrown (because the labels are not drawn yet)
    }
```

Here is the new thread method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// infinite loop to execute every x seconds (using a new thread)
    /// repeater uses cross-thread operation(s) and so CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls has been set to false
    /// MSDN recommends against this, it is executed safely however
    /// </summary>
    private void repeater()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            Thread.Sleep( 5000 ); //sleep (pause) the thread for 5 seconds
            instance = instance + 1; //add to the current instance (this is used to display what "day" we're on
            changePrices(); //change the prices of the stocks
            updateLabels(); //update the form's labels to display the new values
        }
    }
```

Here are the methods the repeater calls every 5 seconds

```
    /// <summary>
    /// this will change the prices every x seconds based on current prices etc
    /// </summary>
    private void changePrices()
    {
        marketController mC = new marketController();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < stocks.Length ; i++ )
        {
            mC.changePrices( stocks [ i ] , i ); //mc for marketController, object reference, change prices will calc the price changes
        }
        return;
    }
```

mC.changePrices doesn't actually do anything yet, but it does not get stuck there.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// method used to update all display labels every x seconds (based on repeater)
    /// </summary>
    public void updateLabels()
    {
        try
        {
            this.userMoneyLabel.Text = "Your money: " + this.getUserMoney().ToString(); //changes the user's money label
            this.currentDayLabel.Text = "Day: " + this.getInstance().ToString(); //changes the day label
            this.setStocksCombined(); //sets the array of combined stock prices and stock names
            this.stockListBox.Items.Clear(); //clear the list box because it will constantly stack the items
            this.stockListBox.Items.AddRange( stocksCombined ); //adds the combined array to the list box (stocks + stockNames)
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Error: " + e );
        }
    }
```

All of the relevant labels update fine, this problem also persisted before I added setStocksCombined() and so I don't believe the problem lies there.

This is the error that is thrown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I haven't opened any additional threads apart from repeater, the repeater normally throws this error when it reached instance 7.

Thanks in advance (hopefully)

---

Edit:

Thanks to @RichardSzalay and @MichaelThePotato I have implemented a timer using this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535833/6639187

Comment: `MSDN recommends against this, it is executed safely however` seems like a weird assumption given that the application crashes. Not saying it is causing it but it might be.

Comment: You should really look into using `Task` to do your background work. Creating threads directly in .net in 2016 is essentially unheard of, and always eyebrow-raise worthy. Tasks, on the other hand, are par for the course.

Comment: what is your sample stock size? What kind of data it contains?

Comment: Do you really think 'CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;' is a good idea? Just don't check?

Comment: Please remove the excessive spacing in your methods. My eyes are bleeding.
CTRL+K+D, Beautify the code!
in a void method no need to return; unless you want another exit point.
reaching the end of the definition is fine.
Now solving the problem...

Comment: using "this" is also not needed. if there's nothing to make the name ambiguous, just take it out.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato I spaced it out just so it was a bit easier to read, not my normal practice :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I had to because without it, the repeater can not execute updatelabels as it belongs to a different thread.

Comment: @RichardSzalay could you please link me an article on tasks? Never heard of it before (new to c#)

Comment: @PeterT - it still can't update the UI. You just disabled a diagnostic telling you so. You now have a program with  built-in race conditions, and you may expect several hard to reproduce failures. Maybe even OOM.

Comment: On Tasks - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Timer to prevent that while loop - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Incomplete code with several other issues. Create a [MCVE] , right now we just have to guess.

Comment: @PeterT https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

One of the methods you use but have not listed is likely to be holding on to references. Use a memory profiler to find out where your app is leaking RedGate does a 14 day free trial.

If your app is not leaking then it is simply trying to load in too much data in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the free tool ClrDbg to inspect the heap of your .Net application and find the cause of the memory issue
https://sourceforge.net/projects/clrdbg/