# how to capture real time stream data in csv or .data file in a windows form Application

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I implemented a function in a windows form application to capture and read needed tabular data from a file (sourcedata.data) and save it in another file (result.data ).
How i and by using the application can capture a real time stream data like such  available here :https://data.sparkfun.com/streams  in csv or .data file to use it.
Or are there any direct waya to read the stream data directly from the website source periodically ?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
    int[] indexes = { 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"sourcedata.data"))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("result.data"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.IndexOf(',') == -1)
                    continue;

                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                string[] row = new string[indexes.Length];
                int insertIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    string val = values[i];

                    if (val.Trim() == "?")
                        goto BREAK;

                    if (indexes.Contains(i))
                        row[insertIndex++] = val;
                }
                rows.Add(row);
                writetext.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row));
                BREAK:;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to run it in the background. google for background worker, or learn how to start threads directly

Comment: what should the threads do ? can you guide me to useful references ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two split your problem into two separated sub problems:

1. Write a method `public static string DownloadData(...)` which will download the data from the source. This can be done by any HTTP client or library you can find like [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) or [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

   - See [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)
2. Add/start a timer which calls this method periodically. You can use classes like [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

   - See [What is the best way to implement a "timer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer)

Comment: are there any direct waya to read the stream data directly from the website source periodically

Comment: @Alex As I wrote it above, you have to write one code which downloads the content and another code which calls this method. There is no `DownloadDataPeriodicallyFromAServer(url, time)` method.

Comment: I have implemented a function to download files successfully, but the csv files from the website can't be downloaded!

Comment: https://data.sparkfun.com/output/mKNlA0vdjAiyJ1p31XEM.csv 
this is a link for example .. in the browser it is being downloaded

Comment: @Alex When the browser can download it then your code can download it as well. Keep in mind that you need to limit the server response as described [in the documentation of phant.io](http://phant.io/docs/output/http/#paging). In your case the URL to use would be https://data.sparkfun.com/output/mKNlA0vdjAiyJ1p31XEM.csv?page=1.

Comment: please see my next answer

Answer (score 0):

@Progman
It is the code

```
 public partial class Download : Form
{
    public Download()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    WebClient client;
    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = txtUrl.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
          {
              Uri uri = new Uri(url);
              string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
              client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.StartupPath + "/" + filename);

          });
            thread.Start();
        }

    }

    private void Download_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
    }

    private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download Completed.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }

    private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            progressBar.Minimum = 0;
            double recieve = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double total = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = recieve / total * 100;
            lblStatus.Text = $"Download {string.Format("{0:0.##}", percentage)}%";
            progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }));
    }
}
```