# Do I have to query the database every second to see if any alarm should start?

Tags: database, desktop-application, alarm

I have a desktop application which has the "Alarm" feature. The way I'm thinking to implement is that when user selects the data and time for alarm it gets stored in the database and my application query the database every second and match the current date and time of the system with all date and time in the database and then notify if matches. I don't think querying the database every second is good. I can't think of any other way around. This application is also going to sync the alarm records across multiple devices so storing in database is a must I guess. 
How do typical alarm application work in which we can set multiple alarms ?
-Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement a "timer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create server layer on top of database. Query from db alarm time, create class who send notifications to client apps when alarm time is done. Maybe try use Quartz library?