# Starting an exe with delay

Tags: c#, process

I want to run a program with a delay of 10 minutes. I used the `Process` to run the program, but after 10 minutes I could not run the command. Could you help me?

```
        Process scriptProc = new Process();
        scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\a.vbs";    
        scriptProc.Start();
        scriptProc.WaitForExit();   
        scriptProc.Close();
```

Comment: Question is too unclear. Please refine and add more detail to your question so people can help you.

Comment: RE "question is unclear": I think they want to launch "C:\a.vbs" 10 minutes after running the C# program.

Comment: sounds for me like the joke apps we wrote when we were teens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` to wait 10 minutes and then executing your code. This is the correct usage of `Timer`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535731/506128

I do recommend going with the `Timer`, since 10 minutes of `Thread.Sleep()` is absurd.

Comment: Well, yeah. It's still a way of doing it, and I also mentioned my view on it. It can reference someone else reading this question in the future. Someone who doesn't want to wait 10 minutes but a few seconds maybe.

Comment: Also that's how you learn the differences between two similar ways.

Comment: What you need to understand is that people won't read everything.  They'll see `Thread.Sleep()` and off they go

Comment: Aight then, I'll update. However this is more of a discussion instead of arguement. I'd rather have reasons before acting :)

Comment: Goodo, hard to tell sometimes on SO.  Thanks very much good sir :)