# How do you make a live-updating time label?

Tags: c#, winforms

Rookie programmer here! I'll explain what I've done so far:

```
        private void frmRegister_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

When the form loads, as I want, the label lblDateTime displays the date and time. However, it only displays the date and time at the point the form loaded.

How do I make it change with the user's computer (live)? Or should I remove this label altogether?

Comment: You need a timer. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535731/3270427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) component on your form and subscribe to the Tick event.
Don't forget to set Enabled to true, or call `Start`.