# Why doesn't the timer start?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

It's simple code that increases a number and shows it in a texView but it's not working and I don't know what is wrong with my code...

here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
         {
             x++;
             textView.Text = x.ToString();
         };
    }
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: I guess the timer instance does not survive when `OnCreate` exits. It is local to the method, it should be local to the instance, where `x` probably lives. also, usually, the event handler is added before the start.

Comment: @dlatikay   x  is before the onCreate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using a SynchronizingObject, `System.Timers.Timer` is calling Elapsed on a threadpool thread, thus you are not on the UI/Main thread (where UI updates need to be performed).

- [Do C# Timers elapse on a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435876/do-c-sharp-timers-elapse-on-a-separate-thread)

So use `RunOnUiThread` to update your UI within the event:

```
timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
{
    x++;
    RunOnUiThread(() => button.Text = x.ToString());
};
```